# Searching for tool to remotely monitor systemd services

Tags: systemd, services, monitoring

I'm searching for a tool to remotely monitor systemd services. This would be used to monitor an embedded device running Linux 5.15. Access to device would be through network interface.

There is access to command line. "systemctl status " and "system-cgtop" commands can be executed, but I would want to make this automatical such, that it would cover many devices.

One possibility would be to install Zabbix client to device and make discovery+monitoring rules for this. It would execute above mentioned commands, but this seems to be re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can use the systemctl option `--host` after setting up the right ssh key on the remote. The best article for this is https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2021/03/03/how-to-manage-systemd-services-remotely/

Comment: True, this answers part of the core question. Anyway, systemd-cgtop does not seem to have such remote control possibility. Also, my first idea was to use Zabbix, which would give me overall of device health at one glimpse.